# Grouped barplot in ggplot2: based on three variables (group, time, protein)

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouped-bar-chart

Maybe someone has run into someissue. I am trying to plot different proteins (e.g., CS, AMPK) in other type points (pre and post), and two different intervention groups (control, treatment). I plot a grouped barplot nicely based on group and time, but I cannot create a unique grouped barplot per protein.

My data has as columns the following variables:
PID, time, group, protein_name, protein_content (in the plot named area)

I used the following code to plot a grouped barplot

```
ggplot(data, aes(group, area, fill=time)) + theme_classic() +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat = "identity")
```

With the following output:
[image]

**How do I create a plot like the one above for each protein rather than using all the protein values as a unique value?** I have 5 different proteins, so I would like to plot 5 different plots like the one above.

Thank you in advance! All help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Perhaps `+ facet_wrap(~protein_name)`.